# PHP FTP put created zip file

Tags: php, ftp, zip

If I try to run this code to upload a new zip file

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open("file.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE);
ftp_fput($ftp_conn, "file.zip", $zip, FTP_BINARY);
```

It displays the error:

> **Warning**: ftp_fput() expects parameter 3 to be resource

How to put a zip file in ftp?

Comment: Try to update the third parameter of the method ftp_put() with the local file path, not the file content

Answer (score 1):

ftp_put working as follows

```
ftp_put(ftp_connection,remote_file,local_file,mode,startpos);
```

In your case

```
ftp_put($ftp_conn, "file.zip", "file.zip", FTP_BINARY);
```

Comment: Also OP needs to close the `ZipArchive` before uploading.

Comment: When put, the zip file is corrupted or damaged. What's my mistake?

Comment: @JasonD'Souza So show us the latest version of your code.